# Angular Fullcalendar view collapses after database change

Tags: angular, firebase, fullcalendar

so I am having this issue since 1 week and I am totally devastated of this.

I am building an Angular study organizing/helping application with the help of Ionic and Firebase.

My data is stored in a Firestore database and one of my functionalities is that when the user adds a Subject to the database it creates automatically an event as well. I am using [fullcalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/) as the calendar to my application.

**My main problem is that when an event is added to the database (only through another view) the calendar view collapses.**
I said only through another view because I have an event add page inside the calendar (basically the calendar view is still there but the addition form is at the top of it) and when I add an event there, the calendar can display that and won't collapse.

[Fullcalendar collapse screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/neyaI.png)

My calendar component is subscribed to the events that are in the database with the following code:

```
return this.db.collection('users').doc(this.getUser()).collection('events').valueChanges();
```

My calendar subscription to the events:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getEventsValue().subscribe(value => {
      this.events = [];
      value.forEach((doc) =>{
        this.events.push({
          title:doc.title, 
          daysOfWeek: [doc.daysOfWeek], 
          startRecur: doc.startDay, 
          startTime: doc.startTime,
          endTime: doc.endTime,
          endRecur:'2021-12-10',
          color: doc.color

        });
      });
      this.calendarOptions.events = this.events;
    });
}
```

CalendarModule:

```
FullCalendarModule.registerPlugins([
dayGridPlugin,
intercationPlugin,
timegridPlugin
])
```

My calendar options:

```
calendarOptions: CalendarOptions = {
headerToolbar: {
  left: 'prev,next today',
  center: 'addEventButton',
  right: 'timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
},
initialView: 'timeGridWeek',
weekends: false,
buttonText: {
  today:    'Ma',
  month:    'Hónap',
  week:     'Hét',
  day:      'Nap',
  list:     'Lista'
},
slotMinTime: "06:00:00",
slotMaxTime: "22:00:00",
locale: "hu",
eventClick: function(info){
  console.log(info);
},
droppable: true,
// editable: true,
customButtons:{
  addEventButton: {
    text: 'Esemény hozzáadása',
    click: () => {
      this.router.navigate(['overview/calendar/add-event']);
    }
  }
}
};
```

Comment: If you're hiding the view containing the calendar while you add the event, then you'll need to run calendar.render() when showing the view. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-render. Or you might get away with calling updateSize() instead - https://fullcalendar.io/docs/updateSize

Comment: @ADyson thank you for the response. Sorry for the late response when you replied I tried to do one of these, but I couldn't resolve. I tried to update the size and render in OnChanges (so I try to call it when the component changes) but nothing happened. I tried out with a button and render, then it worked. Any idea how to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting:
`encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None`